# Is there any way to use ctags with ruby namespacing?

Tags: ruby, vim

When I have classes `ModuleA::Class1` with method `test_method` and `ModuleB::Class2` with `test_method` as well, and somewhere in code I have `ModuleB::Class2.test_method` and click `Ctrl-]` on `test_method` it jumps to wrong `test_method` definition from `ModuleA::Class1`.

Is there any way to make ctags work with Ruby namespaces?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could give [ripper-tags](https://github.com/tmm1/ripper-tags) a try, but I don't have any experience with it.

What I do usually is, if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> doesn't open the correct tag, I just repeat `:tnext` until I reach the correct one.

In case you find that tiring, you could use [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) to have the convenient `[t` and `]t` or manually map

```
nnoremap ]t :tnext<cr>
nnoremap [t :tprevious<cr>
```